# Running Scala Map Reduce code using a web app

Tags: scala, hadoop, web-applications, mapreduce

I have a specific requirement where I have to write few hadoop MR code in scala and then to fire those codes using a web-app and then finally show the results in a web page.

Is this possible ?

If yes is there any framework which I can make use of ?

Regards,

Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. If you mean Hadoop MR jobs then you should look at  [Scalding](https://github.com/twitter/scalding) and [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/).

How big is your data? You should be able to do MR on normal or Parallel Scala collections if the size of your data it not big.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Yes I want to do Hadoop MR Jobs, I will definitely look at Scalding and Spark.